# A question about quantum noise model

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, error-correction, noise

Now, I try to understand some concept of Quantum Noise Model and Quantum Channel. The Quantum Noise can be represented as a quantum operator with their own probability. As far as I concerned,(I dont know if it is right), it totally included Bit Flip, Phase Flip, Bit-phase Flip, Amplitude damping and Phase damping. and all the five noise can happen with their own probability so that the quantum status can be represented as a mixed state.

However, there is a question, The five error below is happened because of systematic gate error and environmental decoherence. So systematic gate error and environmental decoherence can both cause the five error or each of them match some of the error?

And the five noise or error from above can happen independently or not, in other word, can the five error happen in the same time with their own probability?